# Access to the local variable while directive unit testing in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, karma-runner, local-variables

I need to test some directive and for that to get one of its local variables to check its value. The directive itself looks this:

```
angular.module('app').directive('favoritesList', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/directives/favoritesListDirective.html',
    controller: function ($scope, $rootScope, $rootElement, $filter, ContactService, ContactFollowerService, Restangular) {

      var listLimit = 100, // in order to prevent favoritesList *overflow*
          followedFilter = {filters: {followed: true}, page_size:listLimit};

      // get Favorites List
      ContactService.provider.getList( followedFilter ) //
        .then(function(result){
          $scope.favorites=result;
        }, function(message){
          console.warn('Cannot get a Favorites List',message);
        });

      ....


    }
  };
});
```

So, how can I get access to the **followedFilter** variable in the **describe/it** blocks?

Comment: You can't the way this is written. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest breaking out your controller so you can grab it properly. Though it is possible to break a controller off of a directive it can be very difficult - the easiest thing to do is to have the controller stand-alone. For example:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  describe('FavouritesListCtrl', function() {

    var $rootScope, $scope, ctrl;
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, $controller) {
        $rootScope  = _$rootScope_;
        $scope      = $rootScope.$new();

        ctrl = $controller('FavouritesListCtrl',{$scope: $scope});
    }));

    describe('FavouritesListCtrl', function() {
        it('should be defined', function() {
            expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
        });
    });

  });
});
```

Based on this test you'd expect the controller to de defined like so:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .component('favoritesList', {
      bindings: {},
      controllerAs: "vm",
      controller: "FavouritesListCtrl",
      templateUrl: 'example.html'
    });
}());
```

Here I'm making use of component as opposed to directive but they're pretty closely related. If you wanted to test `followedFilter`, for example in initialization:

```
describe('init', function() {
  it('followedFilter should be set to ', function() {
    expect(ctrl.followedFilter).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

This would expect the `followedFilter` to be defined like this in the controller:

```
function FavouritesListCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.followedFilter = {
    //values
  };
}
```